# Taylor polynomial in function composition

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I have the Taylor polynomial of a function f(x):

$$4-5x+2x^2$$

and the Taylor polynomial of a function g(x):

$$2+\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2$$

Both about $$ x=0$$

How can I calculate the Taylor polynomial (at the same point)  of:

$$(gf)(x) $$
?

Comment: Are your $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ actually polynomials? If not, the first three terms of $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ will not be enough to determine the first three terms of $g(f(x))$. In general you would have to find the first so many terms of $f(x)$ and plug it into $g$'s entire power series in order to get the first so many terms of $g(f(x))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, a Taylor polynomial for a function about $x=0$ is $$f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac {f''(0)}{2!}x^2$$

So for a composite function, the Taylor polynomial will be $$(fg)(x)=(fg)(0)+(fg)'(0)x+\frac {(fg)''(0)}{2!}x^2$$

So, you get the followings,

$$(fg)(0)=f(g(0))=f(2)=2$$

$$(fg)'(0)=f'(g(0))g'(0)=f'(2)g'(0)=f'(2)*\frac12$$ (this is where @arctic tern asked you a question)

$$(fg)''(0)=f''(g(0))g'(0)+f'(g(0))g''(0)=f''(2)\frac12-f'(2)\frac14$$

Comment: How do you know $f(2)=2f(2)=2 $? @user115350

Comment: $f(x)=4-5x+2x^2$ and thus f(2)=2, isn't it?

Comment: $4-5x+2x^2$ is the Taylor polynomial of the $f$ function , is the same?

Comment: OK. they are not the same. It's my mistake. It should be kept as $f(2)$ for $(fg)(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

[Faa di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno's_formula) gives the derivatives of $g\circ f$ at $x$ in terms of the value and derivatives of $f$ at $x$ and of $g$ at $f(x)$.  But note that if $f(0) \ne 0$ (as in your example) you need the Taylor series of $g$ about $f(0)$, not about $0$.